# NEventStore with RavenDB in Embedded Mode

Tags: c#, ravendb, neventstore

I am trying to get NEventStore (v4) working with RavenDB in embedded mode.

My connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="EventStore" connectionString="DataDir = ~\Data" />
```

In Application_Start, I set up the Raven Store like this:

```
var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
{
    ConnectionStringName = "EventStore"
};
documentStore.Initialize();
```

This runs before any event store code gets initialized.  I am able to use Raven to save documents at this point.  So Raven is working.

For NEventStore, init looks like this:

```
_store = Wireup.Init()
    .LogToOutputWindow()
    .UsingRavenPersistence("EventStore") 
    .InitializeStorageEngine()
    .UsingJsonSerialization()
    .Compress()
    .UsingSynchronousDispatchScheduler()
    .DispatchTo(new DelegateMessageDispatcher(DispatchCommit))
    .Build();
```

When this runs, I get this error:

> Connection string name: 'EventStore' could not be parsed, unknown
>   option: 'datadir'

In looking at the (RavenDB) source code, it appears that the connection string parser doesn't know that it is reading an embedded connection string.  But I don't see any way of indicating that NEventStore is to use Raven in embedded mode.

Answer (score 0):

The option ['DataDir'](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/Csharp/client-api/setting-up-connection-string) only works with an EmbeddableDocumentStore. NEventstore [creates](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore.Persistence.RavenDB/blob/686d2a757487a3c7518a8d49a1646107479945f5/src/NEventStore.Persistence.RavenDB/RavenPersistenceOptions.cs) a DocumentStore. As far I know you can't change this behavior.

What you could do is to start the Embedded RavenDB with [HTTP enabled](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/Csharp/server/deployment/embedded) and connect to localhost.